# How to get a sum of number from streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get a total price from streambuilder in shopping cart. and assign it to a double. The problem is when the first time i click on the shopping cart, the total price is showing zero. when i refresh the page only then the total will be shown correctly. i believe the initial declaration of `double price = 0;` is what causing it to bring the value zero in the shopping cart screen on the first time shopping cart is open. I've already did some searching on google and it is probably because im not using the asynchronous computation. i've tried and couldn't find a proper solution for this.

[Shopping cart screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1sOR.png)

this is the code for shopping cart

```
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
late String userid = user!.uid;

@override
CollectionReference<Object?> cart() {final CollectionReference cart = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userid).collection('cart');
return cart;
}

Widget bodySection(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: cart().snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
      if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
          child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                    streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                price = documentSnapshot['price'] + price; // to sums up the total price
                String imgurl = documentSnapshot['imgUrl'];
                return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    child: Dismissible(
                      key: Key(documentSnapshot['id']),
                      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                      onDismissed: (direction) {
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      background: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFFFE6E6),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Spacer(),
                            Icon(Icons.delete),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.all(getProportionateScreenWidth(8)),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 88,
                              child: AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 0.88,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                      getProportionateScreenWidth(5)),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: NetworkImage(imgurl),
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 20),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  documentSnapshot['brand'] +
                                      " " +
                                      documentSnapshot['name'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                                  maxLines: 2,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 10),
                                Text.rich(
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "RM " +
                                        (documentSnapshot['price'])
                                            .toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        color: kPrimaryColor),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Spacer(),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "x 1",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ));
              }),
        );
      }
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    });}
```

this is the code where i want to display the total price

```
Widget billSection(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: getProportionateScreenWidth(15),
    horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(30),
  ),
  // height: 174,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
      topRight: Radius.circular(30),
    ),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        offset: Offset(0, -15),
        blurRadius: 20,
        color: Color(0xFFDADADA).withOpacity(0.15),
      )
    ],
  ),
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                  text: "Total:\n",
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "RM " + price.toString(), // display total price
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    ),
                  ],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: getProportionateScreenWidth(190),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: getProportionateScreenHeight(56),
                child: TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    primary: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    "Check Out",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(18),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

The variable price initialization

```
double price = 0;
```

Comment: im not even allowed to vote yet

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry. XD

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to publish the sum as a side-effect while processing the documents, which is a recipe for problems.

A better approach is to make this stream a field in your widget:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userid)
        .collection('cart')
        .snapshots()
```

And then add two `StreamBuilder` widget to your UI: one for the documents themselves, and one for the sum.

You can also:

1. `listen()` to the stream (for example in the constructor of your widget),
2. calculate the sum in there (by looping over the documents, but not rendering anything),
3. then calling `setState` to put the sum into a field,
4. and finally, have a `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` in the UI to render the sum field.

Comment: im sorry, can you give an example code for this, i tried the listen method as you suggest but i get bunch of error. sorry again im quite new to flutter

Comment: It's hard to help with a "bunch of error". Which of the two approaches did you try? Did the approach make sense overall, regardless of the errors? If yes, how did you implement the approach and exactly what error did you get?

Comment: i dont really know how to implement the method you stated above thats why i got errors.  but i did try to use the first method and get no error but it is returning null. this is the code

Comment: please don't post blocks of code in a comment. If you tried to implement the approach from my answer but ran into problems, edit your question (there's a link right under it) to provide an **update** to your question with the relevant code and the problem. I strongly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) too though, as we'll need the minimal-but-complete information on the problem and that link explains why and how quite well.